# ExtJS: Next method executes even before Ext.Ajax.request completes

Tags: extjs4

Below is one function defined in my Extjs code.

```
updateJob : function(button,grid, record) {
    var activeAccordianName = _myAppGlobal.getController('RFBAccordiansController').getActiveAccordianName();
    if(activeAccordianName == 'Lookup') {
        var win = button.up('window'),
        form = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

        var oldRecord = new Object();
        oldRecord.environment=record.get('environment');
        .........
        ..........
        win.close();
        this.submitLookupJobUpdateForm(oldRecord,values);
        record.set(values);
        }

},
```

Everything works fine until the "**this.submitLookupJobUpdateForm(oldRecord,values);**" is called. This method has an Ajax request which executes perfectly but takes some time since I am fetching some data from the database. But the next statement "**record.set(values);**" gets executed even before the Ajax request completes. Below is the submitLookupJobUpdateForm method code

```
submitLookupJobUpdateForm: function(oldRecord,values){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : './LookupUpdateController/LookupUpdate/UpdateJob.do',
        method : 'POST',
        params :
        {
            record : Ext.JSON.encode(oldRecord),
            newValues : values              
        },
        success : function(response)
        {
            var jobInfoJson=response.responseText;
            if (jobInfoJson != "" & jobInfoJson != "[]")
            {
                alert("Updating row");
            } else
            {
                Ext.MessageBox.alert("Failed","Update Failed");
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Can anyone please suggest what should I do so that the "**record.set(values);**" is called after the completion of Ajax request. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ajax request is being performed asynchronously so it wont pause your code until the request completes, which is why your record.set() is being called immediately after your submitLookupJobUpdateForm() call.

I suggest you move your record.set() call into a separate function that gets called in your success handler.

This kind of thing:

```
submitLookupJobUpdateForm: function(oldRecord,values){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : './LookupUpdateController/LookupUpdate/UpdateJob.do',
        method : 'POST',
        params :
        {
            record : Ext.JSON.encode(oldRecord),
            newValues : values              
        },
        success : function(response)
        {
            var jobInfoJson=response.responseText;
            if (jobInfoJson != "" & jobInfoJson != "[]")
            {
                //alert("Updating row");
                this.processRowUpdate();
            } else
            {
                Ext.MessageBox.alert("Failed","Update Failed");
            }
        },
        scope:this
    });
},

processRowUpdate: function() {
    record.set(...);
}
```

This way you can be sure your record.set() waits until the Ajax has succeeded.